# Query Cloudant the number of created documents within 24h using Map Reduce.

Tags: mapreduce, cloudant

I would like to count the number of created documents within 24h using Map Reduce process of IBM Cloudant database. Here is my Map-Reduce code:

```
function (doc) {
    docTime = (new Date(doc.created_at)).getTime();
    currentTime = (new Date()).getTime();
    if ((86400000 - (currentTime - docTime)) > 0) {
          emit(doc.deviceID, 1);
    }
}
```

In the reduce phase, I used the count function to get the total of document. However, the value ***currentTime*** seen to be taken the first time building the Map-Reduce and  not updated for each query.

It would be great if receiving any suggestions to overcome this issues.

Thank you so much.

Comment: Had a similar problem ... Just added created time to the JSON doc I was saving to cloudant. Then created a view based on it.

Answer (score 3):

I think you have a few options here, but I don't think a view is one of them. I believe views are only calculated at insert/update time.

Your first option is to use Cloudant Query. You can create an index on your `created_at` field and use the following selector:

```
"selector": {
   "$and": [
      {"created_at" : { "$gt": 1506874127 }},
      {"created_at": { "$lt": 1506960651 }}
   ]
}
```

The problem with this is you will have to loop through and count all the entries. An alternative route would be to use Cloudant Search. Create a search index in Cloudant similar to the following:

```
{
  "_id": "_design/allDocs",
  "views": {},
  "language": "javascript",
  "indexes": {
    "byCreatedAt": {
      "analyzer": "standard",
      "index": "function (doc) {\n  if (doc.created_at && doc.device_id) {\n    index(\"created_at\", doc.created_at);\n    index(\"device_id\", doc.device_id);\n  }\n}"
    }
  }
}
```

This corresponds to the following when using the Cloudant dashboard:

design doc = `allDocs`

index name = `byCreatedAt`

index function =

```
function (doc) {
  if (doc.created_at && doc.device_id) {
    index("created_at", doc.created_at);
    index("device_id", doc.device_id);
  }
}
```

Then you can run a search using a range - where the range would be the time 24 hours ago to the time now - and specify `group_field=device_id` to group results by device ID. For example,

`https://<YOUR_INSTANCE>.cloudant.com/<YOUR_DB>/_design/allDocs/_search/byCreatedAt?q=created_at%3A[1506874127%20TO%201506960651]&group_field=device_id&limit=1`

Here the search query is:

`created_at:[1506874127 TO 1506960651]`

I am using unix timestamps. You could also use date strings I believe. I also set the limit to 1. This will only return the first entry in each group since you only want the total count (limit = 0 is not allowed for grouped queries). Here is a sample result:

```
{
  "total_rows":3,
  "groups":[
    {
      "by":"1",
      "total_rows":2,
      "rows":[
        {
          "id":"263a81ea76528dead3a4185df3676f62",
          "order":[
            1.0,
            0
          ],
          "fields":{

          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "by":"2",
      "total_rows":1,
      "rows":[
        {
          "id":"d857ac5c58eebde4c21ffdcf3e0fd321",
          "order":[
            1.0,
            0
          ],
          "fields":{

          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

The `by` field is the device ID.

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment. In case of counting the number of documents for each device (identifyed by deviceID in document) like grouping operation, what do I need to set up? Thank you again

Comment: Sorry, I missed the grouping part of your question. Please see revised answer. Note: both the search index and query have been changed.

Comment: Many thanks for your help. In case of grouping by device_id of cloudant search, Cloudant limits only 10 group per request. That means if our database has 100 devices. This will be impossible or lead to loop query again. Do you have any suggestions about that? Thank you so much for your help

Comment: Unfortunately I think you are going to have to page through the results.

Comment: I found an alternative way is use "counts" to solve it. Thank you so much for your help