# Correct way to filter by date on Cloudant

Tags: cloudant

I want to know the correct way to filter or group data in cloudant database by date range.

Docs have the date in millisecond, so when I tried to grouping by date, there are no groups because the date is different for each document.

I try with cloudant views, but the results there are no reactivity and I need it.

Exist any way to group data by date range?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Query Cloudant the number of created documents within 24h using Map Reduce.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46527370/query-cloudant-the-number-of-created-documents-within-24h-using-map-reduce)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the answer to this other question, which is about grouping by day but the idea is the same.

[Query Cloudant the number of created documents within 24h using Map Reduce.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46527370/query-cloudant-the-number-of-created-documents-within-24h-using-map-reduce/)